# Python's Max function auto rounds up results?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a very simple code using numpy.vectorize to apply a max function to each element of a numpy array. The results that I'm getting is strange in the sense that they are automatically rounded up to the next interger. Here is the code:

```
np.random.seed(0)
simulss = np.exp(np.cumsum((5/100 - 0.5*0.2**2)*(1/365) + np.random.normal(0,1,(365*5,100000))*0.2*(1/365)**0.5,axis=0))
np.vectorize(lambda x:max(0,x-1))(simulss[-1])
```

`simulss` is a numpy array of random numbers, the lambda function above with `max(0,x-1)` auto rounds up the results. However, if I put in `max(0,1-x)` the results are as expected.

```
np.random.seed(0)
simulss = np.exp(np.cumsum((5/100 - 0.5*0.2**2)*(1/365) + np.random.normal(0,1,(365*5,100000))*0.2*(1/365)**0.5,axis=0))
np.vectorize(lambda x:max(0,1-x))(simulss[-1])
```

I have tried to find an explanation to this but I'm truly stuck since it's such a simple function and I can't think of a reason why this is happening. I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, don't do `np.vectorize(lambda x:max(0, x-1))`. You can use built-in numpy vector operations for this: `y = np.maximum(0, simulss[-1] - 1)`

Using `vectorize` with a lambda will be substantially slower than using the proper functionality built into numpy.

---

Now, regarding your current code, the issue is simply that the `vectorize` operation is guessing what data type your result array should be based on the first result. In your first case, the first result is `0` : integer zero. As such, numpy assumes your data is integer, and creates an integer array accordingly. In your second case, the first result is a double, so numpy creates a floating point array accordingly. If for some reason you **must** use `vectorize` with this `lambda`, then the solution is just to change it to `max(0.0, x-1)` - note that the zero is now a floating point number.